# Revenue Cat - grandfather in old users

Tags: ios, swift, revenuecat

I'm a bit new to coding and to Revenue Cat. I just want to make sure this will work before transitioning from sandbox to production, since there's no way to test it in sandbox.

```
Purchases.shared.restoreTransactions { (purchaserInfo, error) in

        let originalPurchaseDate = purchaserInfo?.originalPurchaseDate

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
        let switchOverDate = formatter.date(from: "2020/06/29 00:00")

        if originalPurchaseDate! < switchOverDate! {
            // unlock all content
        }
}
```

Will this let me grandfather in my old users (who paid for my app) when I switch to subscription?

Thank you!

Comment: "grandfather", I think there is something lost in translation here.

Comment: Nothing lost here, _grandfather in old users_ means that he wants to allow old users (already paid for the app) to use the application for free when the business model will be switched to the subscription. I wouldn't say it's a well known term, but it's used pretty often.

Comment: Thats right, thanks @zrzka

Comment: This wont work. [`restoreTransactions`](https://sdk.revenuecat.com/ios/Classes/RCPurchases.html#/c:objc(cs)RCPurchases(im)restoreTransactionsWithCompletionBlock:) restores in-app purchases. What you're looking for is the App Store receipt validation and the [original application version](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW_9) (= `CFBundleVersion` aka build version).

Comment: Your last paid version of the app has a build version set to 15. Your new free version (with in-app purchases) of the app has a build version set to 16. Get the App Store receipt, validate it, extract build version and grandfather the user if the build version is <= 15. Original application version corresponds to the value of `CFBundleVersion` (in iOS) in the `Info.plist` file when the purchase was originally made. Lot of tutorials [about it](https://fluffy.es/migrate-paid-app-to-iap/), [Decoding an Apple App Store Receipt](https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/dissecting-an-app-store-receipt), ...

Comment: Thank you! Are you saying RevenueCat has no way to solve this problem using their SDK?

Comment: This will work.  [ `originalPurchaseDate`] (https://sdk.revenuecat.com/ios/Classes/RCPurchaserInfo.html#/c:objc(cs)RCPurchaserInfo(py)originalPurchaseDate).  Using dates is actually more capable then just checking for the app version; especially if your pricing wasn't tied to specific app versions.  You could white list certain date ranges if you needed to, but the accepted answer is ideal if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll actually want to check the original application version here. This is available on the RevenueCat iOS SDK and will be the `CFBundleVersion` of the original app version the user downloaded.

```swift
Purchases.shared.restoreTransactions { (purchaserInfo, error) in
    
    // Make sure there weren't any errors...
    
    if let originalApplicationVersion = purchaserInfo?.originalApplicationVersion {
        if originalApplicationVersion < "your_build_number_string" {
            // Legacy user! Unlock content
        }
    }
    
    // Check if user restored another purchase...
}
```

**Important:**

Remember the CFBundleVersion is the *build* number, not the app version. Also:

> In the sandbox environment, the value of this field is always “1.0”.
>
> Source:
> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html

Comment: Just to confirm-- this doesn't require the user to have made IAPs? Because my users only paid up front.

Comment: That's correct, in production a device receipt gets created upon installation that contains the original application versionl

Comment: @enc_life Where can you find the build number for your app ? (What I am guessing is that it's not a build number of a specific version, after all every version can have similar build numbers)

Comment: I note that restoreTransactions has been renamed by RevenueCat to restorePurchases